# Configure subdomain in express-subdomain?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, googledns

I am trying to use the directions given in 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain
to set up subdomain.
I a hosting my server in amazon EC2 and the DNS provider is google-DNS.

but I am getting error while accessing the page.

```
404. That’s an error.
```

The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

So I need to do any configuration in EC2 or in my DNS?